# Changing the name of a USB device

Tags: usb, 22.04, rename

I did a search and came up empty so here I am.

First of, I'm new and old to Ubuntu/Linux. What I mean is I've used it on and off for years, but at this point I feel like I know about as much as a standard Mac user does about their machine.

What I am attempting to do is rename a USB device. Currently I have 2 devices that show the same names and I want to change them so I can easily identify which one is which.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and other the lsusb I'm not sure where to start, but here is the info from that,

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0079:0011 DragonRise Inc. Gamepad

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0079:0011 DragonRise Inc. Gamepad

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d20 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

As you can see Device 16 and 3 have the same name, along with Device 8 and 9.

I would really like to call them something like DragonRise1 DragonRise2.

Any help would be great. Also thanks in advance, and sorry if this ends up be really simple and I've just completely missed how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The data reported by `lsusb` comes from the firmware in the USB devices themselves, which makes it very difficult – and generally impossible – to change these values. Sometimes you can cheat [with `udev` tweaks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-there-a-way-to-change-device-names-in-dev-directory), but this generally does not work when there are multiple devices with the same product ID 

Comment: The usb names are in file /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids so you may try changing a name there.  Your gamepad is pretty early in the list, page one or two.

Comment: I'll give that a shot ubfan1, thank you